# Python - pchip warnings

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

Whenever I use the scipy's pchip interpolation for tensor product interpolation, I get the following two warnings:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/polyint.py:894:
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  whmean = 1.0/(w1+w2)*(w1/mk[1:] + w2/mk[:-1])

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/polyint.py:874:    
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return np.where((d1==0) | (m0==0), 0.0, 1.0/(1.0/m0+1.0/d1))
```

Does anybody know what could be causing this?  The output of my interpolation still seems correct.

Comment: Is your `x` array strictly monotonic?  You'll get warnings like that if there is a repeated value in `x`.

Comment: Yes.  I have no repeated values and data is always increasing.